# How to set up cron job in Linux to delete all regular files?

Tags: linux, cron

I need to set up a job to delete all of the regular files in the `/home/admin` directory on the second day of every month at 8:30 A.M.
It seems like wrong command:

```
# crontab -e
30 08 02 * /bin/find /home/admin -type f -exec /bin/rm {} ";"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `30 08 02 * *` and `\;`

```
# crontab -e
30 08 02 * * /bin/find /home/admin -type f -exec /bin/rm {} \;
```

Now it will work.

Comment: Notice that there nothing wrong with using `";"` at the end of the command in when using `-exec` in `find`. It's a character longer, but IMHO looks nicer in a script.

Comment: Using a `+` instead of the quoted semicolon has its merits.  It means that `find` will execute the command (`rm` in this case) with multiple file names each time.

Answer (score 2):

The `crontab(5)` manual specifies *five* time fields:

```
 field         allowed values
 -----         --------------
 minute        0-59
 hour          0-23
 day of month  1-31
 month         1-12 (or names, see below)
 day of week   0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

Your example only has *four*.

This would make the cron job run correctly:

```
30 8 2 * * /bin/find /home/admin -type f -exec /bin/rm {} ";"
```

For a more efficient and quicker cleanup:

```
30 8 2 * * /bin/find /home/admin -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: There's also GNU `find`'s `-delete` option.